# Calling excel VBA subroutine with arguments

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a subroutine that accepts a range as an argument. Something like this:

```
Sub Test(dataRange As Range)

    Sheet2.Range("A1").Cells.value = dataRange.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

However when I try to select the range on Excel and run it, I get a "Reference is not valid" error.

Note: I am trying to run this by going into the Developer tab and clicking on the "Macros" button. In there I type in `Test($A$2:$B$4)`, and then I get the error.

Is there a way to call a custom VBA subroutine from an Excel spreadsheet and pass arguments to it?

Thanks

Comment: It's really surprising that you can see `Sub`s with argument list in your macro list...

Comment: @CST-Link you can't.  I think OP is trying to simply manually type in the sub name & arguments.

Comment: You simply can't pass a Range object like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not a generalized answer, it should work for your purposes:

```
Sub Test(Optional dataRange As Range = Nothing)
    If dataRange is Nothing then Set dataRange = Range(Selection.Address)
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Cells.value = dataRange.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

From the macro menu, simply type in `Test` and hit the "Run" button.

This will use the current `Selection` as the data range.

Alternatively, use an `InputBox` to capture the range argument:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim dataRange as Range
    Set dataRange = Application.InputBox("Select range", Type:=8)
    If dataRange is Nothing then Exit Sub
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Cells.value = dataRange.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I went with the second option. It was just what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You would need quotes around the range:

> Test(Range("$A$2:$B$4"))